# Rails 4 automatically generated RSpec test for delete is failing, even while the feature works in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the automatically generated test for the destroy action in Rails 4, as part of the spec for `vehicles_controller.rb`:

```
describe "DELETE destroy" do
     it "destroys the requested vehicle" do
       vehicle = Vehicle.create! valid_attributes
        expect {
          delete :destroy, {:id => vehicle.to_param}, valid_session
        }.to change(Vehicle, :count).by(-1)
     end

    it "redirects to the vehicles list" do
      vehicle = Vehicle.create! valid_attributes
      delete :destroy, {:id => vehicle.to_param}, valid_session
      response.should redirect_to(vehicles_url)
    end
end
```

and here is what I've got in the controller, again very standard:

```
def destroy
  @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id])
  @vehicle.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Vehicle has been deleted"
  redirect_to vehicles_url
end
```

This works just fine in the app itself -- when you delete a vehicle, it redirects back to the vehicles_url, and the entry is deleted from the database. The server log looks completely normal as well. However, when I run the specs, they fail as follows:

```
1) VehiclesController DELETE destroy destroys the requested vehicle
   Failure/Error: expect {
     count should have been changed by -1, but was changed by 0
   # ./spec/controllers/vehicles_controller_spec.rb:148:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) VehiclesController DELETE destroy redirects to the vehicles list
   Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(vehicles_url)
     Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/vehicles> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/>.
     Expected "http://test.host/vehicles" to be === "http://test.host/".
   # ./spec/controllers/vehicles_controller_spec.rb:156:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can anyone point me to what might be going on here to make the test fail? Thanks for any help!

Edit: here is some additional information about before filters that could be affecting things. In the vehicles_controller, since I am using the gem CanCan, I have `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top. This controller is also being tested for the ability to create and update, and those specs are passing, so I assumed that was not interfering, plus it wasn't failing with any messages to do with permissions. Maybe I need to make a change to the default `let(:valid_session) { {} }` at the top of the controller spec? I was leaving that alone because, as I said, it was fine for all the other actions besides delete.

Further edit:
In light of a link provided below, I edited my spec to be :

```
describe "DELETE destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested vehicle" do
      vehicle = Vehicle.create! valid_attributes
      expect {
        delete :destroy, :id => vehicle.to_param, valid_session
      }.to change(Vehicle, :count).by(-1)
    end

    it "redirects to the vehicles list" do
      vehicle = Vehicle.create! valid_attributes
      delete :destroy, :id => vehicle.to_param, valid_session
      response.should redirect_to(vehicles_url)
    end
end
```

Now, if I try to run the specs, I receive this syntax error:

`/home/kathryn/testing/spec/controllers/vehicles_controller_spec.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)`

Line 150 refers to the line in the first spec that begins with `delete :destroy`, where the change was made.

Comment: I have migrated my test database, because I have about 20 other specs that are passing. I will add a note to the original post regarding the before filters.

Answer (score 5):

You are most likely encountering an authorization error.  Try adding `flash[:alert].should == nil` after your `delete` operation in either test.  If you are having an authorization problem, you'll get something like `"You are not authorized to access this page."` in your test failures.

The biggest clue to this is that your tests are also failing with:

> ```
> Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/vehicles> but was a
> redirect to <http://test.host/>.
> ```

A typical implementation of authorization failure redirects to the root path.

I'm personally not a fan of the `, valid_session` approach to handling sign-in.  If you're using Devise, you should use their test helpers and sign in appropriately.  E.g.

```
describe VehiclesController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before(:each) do
    sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  . . .
```

Then (*and this is important!*) remove all the `, valid_session` parameters, otherwise they'll override the session that devise has set up for you with the `sign_in` method.

That's the simplest form; this will still fail if some users can (e.g.) delete and others can't, so for those cases you might want to create a separate `describe "Admin users can" do` ... `end` block of tests, and have a `before(:each)` which calls `sign_in` with an admin user.

I hope that helps, and best of luck!

Comment: Ok, but how would you do this if you are not using Devise and don't have the sign_in function available to you?  How would you do the valid_session method?  I can't find an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting in trouble with the passing of your arguments to `delete`. See the method definition at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-delete.

You can use either:

```
delete :destroy, {id: vehicle.to_param, session: valid_session}
```

or

```
delete :destroy, id: vehicle:to_param, session: valid_session
```

I'm not exactly sure what's happening inside of `ActionController` with the last two parameters you're passing in, but it can't be right.

Comment: That person's situation seems entirely relevant to my problem, but unfortunately when I take it out of the hash, I get the error `/home/kathryn/testing/spec/controllers/vehicles_controller_spec.rb:150: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting => (SyntaxError)`. Thanks for that link though.

Comment: Can you post your new code? The syntax error should be straightforward to fix.

Comment: I'll add the new code to the bottom of my original post. What I did was remove the curly braces so that it was no longer a ruby hash. Perhaps this had other syntactic consequences that I didn't anticipate. Thank you for looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's parser gets confused with inline hashes. You probably want:

```
    delete :destroy, {:id => vehicle.to_param}, valid_session
```